# Gentoo emerge shows dependency conflict

Tags: gentoo, fontconfig, portage, software-conflict

When I try to run this command:

```
emerge -avuDN world
```

I get this message:

```
WARNING: One or more updates have been skipped due to a dependency conflict:

media-libs/freetype:2

  (media-libs/freetype-2.4.10-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) conflicts with
    >=media-libs/freetype-2.2.1[lcdfilter] required by (media-libs/fontconfig-2.9.0::lcd-filtering, ebuild scheduled for merge)
```

How should I resolve this dependency conflict?

I've already tried to reinstall ***fontconfig*** and ***freetype***, I've even set the **~x86** for them in `/etc/portage/package.keywords`.

I'm kind of lost, and already tried Googling.  Can anybody help me?

---

Portage version:

```
Portage 2.1.11.9 (default/linux/x86/10.0/desktop, gcc-4.5.4, glibc-2.15-r2, 3.6.1-gentoo i686)
```

Linux kernel:

```
Linux genta 3.6.1-gentoo #1 SMP Thu Oct 11 19:52:23 NOVT 2012 i686 Genuine Intel(R) CPU T2300 @ 1.66GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Will be glad to provide any logs or configs ASAP.

Comment: Would be there any suggestions? Maybe I should look into some specific forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mask freetype >= 2.2.1

or

```
emerge -C fontconfig-2.9.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually the problem got solved by itself... One day I've launched `emerge --sync && emerge -avuDN world`, and the **freetype** warning has gone!